# Ordenamiento de una Lista por los valores de las Listas hijas. Java 8/11

Tags: java, java-stream

Desarrolle una solución, no fue la más hermosa pero me saca por el momento del problema. Les comparto el link donde puse el código y resultados.

https://cajadearenaparafragmentoscodigo.blogspot.com/2022/02/es-stackoverflow-com-questions-515248.html
código un poco mas formal.
https://github.com/aybramadues/sandboxJava/blob/main/515248.java

*Si alguien logra hacer una mejor versión será bienvenida.*

---

espero puedan ayudarme.

Datos sin ordenar (ejemplo):

> ItemPrincipal{id=1, nombre=producto 1, fecha=27/12/1932,
> urgente=false,  items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000,
> fecha=3/6/1957, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001,
> fecha=29/5/1908, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item 1002,
> fecha=6/10/1915, urgente=false} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=2, nombre=producto
> 2, fecha=13/12/1950, urgente=true,  items=[Detalle{id=1000,
> nombre=Item 1000, fecha=21/9/1935, urgente=true} , Detalle{id=1001,
> nombre=Item 1001, fecha=15/8/1961, urgente=true} ]}
> ItemPrincipal{id=3, nombre=producto 3, fecha=6/5/1977, urgente=false,
> items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000, fecha=5/8/1913,
> urgente=true} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=4, nombre=producto 4,
> fecha=13/6/1933, urgente=true,  items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item
> 1000, fecha=22/10/1973, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item
> 1001, fecha=3/11/1983, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item
> 1002, fecha=24/6/1984, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1003, nombre=Item
> 1003, fecha=5/8/1915, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1004, nombre=Item
> 1004, fecha=21/11/1947, urgente=false} ]}

Busco que queden ordenados por los elementos de los datos Detalle por urgente y fecha:

> ItemPrincipal{id=2, nombre=producto 2, fecha=13/12/1950, urgente=true,
> items=[   Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000, fecha=21/9/1935,
> urgente=true} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001, fecha=15/8/1961,
> urgente=true} ]}
>
> ItemPrincipal{id=1, nombre=producto 1, fecha=27/12/1932,
> urgente=false,  items=[   , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001,
> fecha=29/5/1908, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item 1002,
> fecha=6/10/1915, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000,
> fecha=3/6/1957, urgente=false} ]}
>
> ItemPrincipal{id=4, nombre=producto 4, fecha=13/6/1933, urgente=true,
> items=[  Detalle{id=1003, nombre=Item 1003, fecha=5/8/1915,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1004, nombre=Item 1004, fecha=21/11/1947,
> urgente=false}     , Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000, fecha=22/10/1973,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001, fecha=3/11/1983,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item 1002, fecha=24/6/1984,
> urgente=false} ,  ]}

Tengo un aproximado ordenando la lista principal, pero no se como pasarlo a las listas hijas:

```
System.out.println("Ordenados?");
         Comparator<ItemPrincipal> comparadorMultiple= 
                 Comparator.comparing(ItemPrincipal::getFecha)
                         .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(ItemPrincipal::getUrgente));
         productos.stream().sorted(comparadorMultiple).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Salida del código:

> ItemPrincipal{id=1, nombre=producto 1, fecha=4/7/1910, urgente=false,
> items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000, fecha=2/9/1966,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001, fecha=24/6/1959,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item 1002, fecha=7/8/1940,
> urgente=false} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=2, nombre=producto 2,
> fecha=30/3/1932, urgente=true,  items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item
> 1000, fecha=10/9/1960, urgente=true} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item
> 1001, fecha=14/5/1905, urgente=true} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=3,
> nombre=producto 3, fecha=4/7/1945, urgente=false,
> items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000, fecha=4/6/2002,
> urgente=true} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=4, nombre=producto 4,
> fecha=10/1/1946, urgente=true,  items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item
> 1000, fecha=29/11/1946, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item
> 1001, fecha=25/1/2008, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item
> 1002, fecha=4/8/1931, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1003, nombre=Item
> 1003, fecha=25/5/1938, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1004, nombre=Item
> 1004, fecha=29/3/1979, urgente=false} ]}

Ordenados

> ItemPrincipal{id=4, nombre=producto 4, fecha=10/1/1946, urgente=true,
> items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000, fecha=29/11/1946,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001, fecha=25/1/2008,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item 1002, fecha=4/8/1931,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1003, nombre=Item 1003, fecha=25/5/1938,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1004, nombre=Item 1004, fecha=29/3/1979,
> urgente=false} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=2, nombre=producto 2,
> fecha=30/3/1932, urgente=true,  items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item
> 1000, fecha=10/9/1960, urgente=true} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item
> 1001, fecha=14/5/1905, urgente=true} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=1,
> nombre=producto 1, fecha=4/7/1910, urgente=false,
> items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000, fecha=2/9/1966,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001, fecha=24/6/1959,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item 1002, fecha=7/8/1940,
> urgente=false} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=3, nombre=producto 3,
> fecha=4/7/1945, urgente=false,  items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item
> 1000, fecha=4/6/2002, urgente=true} ]}

Pongo el código de lo que llevo, espero puedan ayudarme.

```
package ejemplo;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author tempo001
 */
public class Ejemplo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.text.ParseException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        List<ItemPrincipal> productos = new ArrayList<>();

        productos.add(new ItemPrincipal(1, "producto 1", generaFecha(), false, generaListaRandom(3)));
        productos.add(new ItemPrincipal(2, "producto 2", generaFecha(), true, generaListaRandom(2)));
        productos.add(new ItemPrincipal(3, "producto 3", generaFecha(), false, generaListaRandom(1)));
        productos.add(new ItemPrincipal(4, "producto 4", generaFecha(), true, generaListaRandom(5)));

        for (ItemPrincipal p : productos) {
            System.out.println(p.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("Ordenados?");
        Comparator<ItemPrincipal> comparadorMultiple
                = Comparator.comparing(ItemPrincipal::getFecha)
                        .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(ItemPrincipal::getUrgente).reversed()
                        );
        productos.stream().sorted(comparadorMultiple).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static LocalDate generaFecha() throws ParseException {
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();

        int year = randBetween(1900, 2010);

        gc.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, year);

        int dayOfYear = randBetween(1, gc.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));

        gc.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfYear);
        DateTimeFormatter JEFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        // parsing the string to convert it into date
        int idia = gc.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int imes = (gc.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH) + 1);
        String dia = agregaCero(idia);
        String mes = agregaCero(imes);
        LocalDate local_date = LocalDate.parse(dia + "/" + mes + "/" + gc.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR), JEFormatter);
        return local_date;
    }

    private static String agregaCero(int valor) {
        String cadena = "";
        if (valor < 10) {
            cadena = "0" + valor;
        } else {
            cadena = String.valueOf(valor);
        }
        return cadena;
    }

    public static int randBetween(int start, int end) {
        return start + (int) Math.round(Math.random() * (end - start));
    }

    private static List generaListaRandom(int total) throws ParseException {
        List<Detalle> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            lista.add(
                    new Detalle(i + 1000, "Item " + (i + 1000), generaFecha(), total < 3)
            );
        }

        return lista;
    }
}

class ItemPrincipal {

    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private LocalDate fecha;
    private Boolean urgente;
    private List<Detalle> items;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public LocalDate getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(LocalDate fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Boolean getUrgente() {
        return urgente;
    }

    public void setUrgente(Boolean urgente) {
        this.urgente = urgente;
    }

    public ItemPrincipal() {
    }

    public ItemPrincipal(int id, String nombre, LocalDate fecha, Boolean urgente, List<Detalle> items) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.urgente = urgente;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ItemPrincipal{" + "id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", fecha=" + fecha + ", urgente=" + urgente + ",\n items=" + items.toString() + "}";
    }

}

class Detalle {

    private int id;
    private String nombre;
    private LocalDate fecha;
    private Boolean urgente;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public LocalDate getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(LocalDate fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public Boolean getUrgente() {
        return urgente;
    }

    public void setUrgente(Boolean urgente) {
        this.urgente = urgente;
    }

    public Detalle() {
    }

    public Detalle(int id, String nombre, LocalDate fecha, Boolean urgente) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.urgente = urgente;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Detalle{" + "id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", fecha=" + fecha + ", urgente=" + urgente + "}\n";
    }
}
```

**Nueva salida de consola con las correcciones.**

> ItemPrincipal{id=1, nombre=producto 1, fecha=1952-06-14,
> urgente=false,  items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000,
> fecha=1934-08-22, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001,
> fecha=1978-09-09, urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item 1002,
> fecha=1934-09-13, urgente=false} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=2,
> nombre=producto 2, fecha=1999-12-20, urgente=true,
> items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000, fecha=1903-04-05,
> urgente=true} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001, fecha=1998-11-10,
> urgente=true} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=3, nombre=producto 3,
> fecha=1952-02-14, urgente=false,  items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item
> 1000, fecha=1971-11-25, urgente=true} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=4,
> nombre=producto 4, fecha=1907-11-26, urgente=true,
> items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000, fecha=1931-02-23,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001, fecha=1948-04-21,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item 1002, fecha=1972-04-11,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1003, nombre=Item 1003, fecha=1937-12-03,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1004, nombre=Item 1004, fecha=1902-05-28,
> urgente=false} ]}

**Ordenacion de por datos de los ItemsPrincipal**

> ItemPrincipal{id=4, nombre=producto 4, fecha=1907-11-26, urgente=true,
> items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000, fecha=1931-02-23,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001, fecha=1948-04-21,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item 1002, fecha=1972-04-11,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1003, nombre=Item 1003, fecha=1937-12-03,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1004, nombre=Item 1004, fecha=1902-05-28,
> urgente=false} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=3, nombre=producto 3,
> fecha=1952-02-14, urgente=false,  items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item
> 1000, fecha=1971-11-25, urgente=true} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=1,
> nombre=producto 1, fecha=1952-06-14, urgente=false,
> items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item 1000, fecha=1934-08-22,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item 1001, fecha=1978-09-09,
> urgente=false} , Detalle{id=1002, nombre=Item 1002, fecha=1934-09-13,
> urgente=false} ]} ItemPrincipal{id=2, nombre=producto 2,
> fecha=1999-12-20, urgente=true,  items=[Detalle{id=1000, nombre=Item
> 1000, fecha=1903-04-05, urgente=true} , Detalle{id=1001, nombre=Item
> 1001, fecha=1998-11-10, urgente=true} ]}

El Código fue actualizado

Answer (score 0):

Al usar `Comparator` en un `String` lo que hace es ordenar alfabeticamente,por ende si tienes una fecha en formato String ¿? ...no tiene lógica tratar de ordenarlo usando Comparator ,pero si usando usando un tipo de fecha ejemplo un [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) para ello habra que modificar el atributo fecha de tu clase Item principal y el metodo `generarFecha` para que te devuelva un `LocalDate`

```
  public static LocalDate generaFecha() throws ParseException{
        GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
        int year = randBetween(1900, 2010);
        gc.set(gc.YEAR, year);
        int dayOfYear = randBetween(1, gc.getActualMaximum(gc.DAY_OF_YEAR));
        gc.set(gc.DAY_OF_YEAR, dayOfYear);
        return LocalDate.of(gc.get(gc.YEAR),(gc.get(gc.MONTH) + 1),gc.get(gc.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
```

Para el comparator con tipo Boolean,puedes hacer uso de [reversed](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparator-reversed-method-in-java-with-examples/)

```
System.out.println("Ordenados?");
        Comparator<ItemPrincipal> comparadorMultiple= 
             Comparator.comparing(ItemPrincipal::getUrgente).reversed().thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(ItemPrincipal::getFecha));  
            
        productos.stream().sorted(comparadorMultiple).forEach(System.out::println);
```

En tu metodo generListRandom puedes mantener el String usando `String.valueOf(generaFecha())` para que no te marque error ;)

Comment: Lo que busco es que se ordenen de acuerdo a las listan internas. Lo que me comentaste de las fechas y booleanos lo agregue y mejore el código en ese sentido.

Comment: @Amadeus,  Aplica lo mismo en la lista que guarda los objetos de la clase Detalle ,también cambia el atributo fecha de esa clase a LocalDate,viendo tu ejercicio para ese ordenamiento solo aplicalo a la fecha no tiene sentido aplicar al valor boolean por que todos son iguales